# java apache poi - xwpfparagraph to string conversion

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

Reading the docx file and try to stored in string variable
below is my code

```
try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fileInputStream);
            List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();
            for (XWPFParagraph para : paragraphs) {
                System.out.println(para.getText());
                docContent = para.getText();
            }
            fileInputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

its Read the content successfully, but its not stored the entire content in string variable (`docContent`),

Answer (score 2):

> You have not concatenate the string `docContent += para.getText();`
>   use `+` for concatenation